# jvectormap: NS_ERROR_FAILURE on firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jvectormap

I use jVectorMap (jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js)

And I try to display the map: jquery-jvectormap-fr-merc.js as follow:

```
$('#france_regions').vectorMap({
    map: 'fr_merc'
});
```

But I got on Firefox:

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE:
```

It seems it because I set the map on a hidden (jquery hide() function) element.

Is there any other way to set the map without render it each time $('#france_regions') become visible ?